# Really Simple Slideshow open link in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I am using the [Really Simple slideshow](http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow) and nowhere in the page does it have a way to click on a slideshow to open in a new window or tab (`target="_blank"`) to certain links.

I have the following, but it still opens in the same page:

```
<html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/css/style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/js/jquery.rs.slideshow.js?v1.4.10"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                var opts = {
                    controls: {
                        playPause: {auto: false},
                        previousSlide: {auto: false},
                        nextSlide: {auto: false},
                        index: {auto: false}
                    },
                    slide_data_selectors: {
                        caption: {selector: 'div.caption', attr: false}
                    },
                    effect: 'slideLeft',
                    interval: 4, 
                    transition: 500
                };
                $('.rs-slideshow').rsfSlideshow(opts);

            });     

</script>


</head>

<body>

        <div class="main">
            <section class="demo-section clearfix" id="demo-1">
                <div id="slideshow-capts-links" class="rs-slideshow">
                    <div class="slide-container" style="">
                        <img src="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/images/morzine-2011-a.png" class="rsf-slideshow-image" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; ">
                            <div class="slide-caption">This is a caption for the first slide.</div>
                    </div>
                    <ol class="slides">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/images/morzine-2011-a.png" ></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/images/morzine-2011-b.png" target="_blank" data-link-to="http://reallysimpleworks.com"></a>
                                <div class="caption">
                                                <p>This slide has the hyperlink</p>
                                </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/images/morzine-2011-c.png"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
            </section>      
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

I have tried the following code as suggested by [Jigar Savla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13185664) and [yurtdweller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13183936) but it keeps opening in the same page. I had tried in Chrome and IE.

```
<html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/css/style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/js/jquery.rs.slideshow.js?v1.4.10"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                var opts = {
                    controls: {
                        playPause: {auto: false},
                        previousSlide: {auto: false},
                        nextSlide: {auto: false},
                        index: {auto: false}
                    },
                    slide_data_selectors: {
                        caption: {selector: 'div.caption', attr: false}
                    },
                    effect: 'slideLeft',
                    interval: 4, 
                    transition: 500
                };
                $('.rs-slideshow').rsfSlideshow(opts);

                $('a.open_in_new_window').attr('target', '_blank');


            });     

    </script>


</head>

<body>

        <div class="main">
            <section class="demo-section clearfix" id="demo-1">
                <div id="slideshow-capts-links" class="rs-slideshow">
                    <div class="slide-container" style="">
                        <img src="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/images/morzine-2011-a.png" class="rsf-slideshow-image" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; ">
                            <div class="slide-caption">This is a caption for the first slide.</div>
                    </div>
                    <ol class="slides">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/images/morzine-2011-a.png" ></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="open_in_new_window" href="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/images/morzine-2011-b.png" data-link-to="http://reallysimpleworks.com"></a>
                                <div class="caption">
                                                <p>This slide has the hyperlink</p>
                                </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/demo/images/morzine-2011-c.png"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
            </section>      
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Edit after answer**

OK, I got it! 
Thanks to [Jigar Savla's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13185664) code sample, I just added a couple new lines in the Javascript:

`// Under if (slide.link_to)` ... 
`if (slide.link_to_new_page) {
$img = $('<a href="' + slide.link_to_new_page + '" target="_blank"></a>').append($img);
}`

`// Under link_to: {selector: 'a', attr: 'data-link-to'},`  ...
`link_to_new_page: {selector: 'a', attr: 'data-link-to-new-page'}`,

And in the html changed`data-link-to=http://google.com` to `data-link-to-new-page=http://google.com`

Now if I just want to use the link and have it open in the same page I use `data-link-to`, otherwise `data-link-to-new-page`.

Worked great!!
THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i would have asked you to add a separate class for each anchor tag that you need to have a link to open in new window.

say for example if you have used **open_in_new_window** as class name to open links in new window than the code would become:

```
$('a.open_in_new_window').attr('target', '_blank');
```

hope this helps ;)

Comment: I added this code right after `$('.rs-slideshow').rsfSlideshow(opts);` and added `class="open_in_new_window" ` on the `<a>` tag where `data-link-to="http://reallysimpleworks.com"` is located, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: yeah i have just checked, you can do with this `$('a.open_in_new_window').$(this).attr('target', '_blank');` insert this code right after `$('.rs-slideshow').rsfSlideshow(opts);`
cheers! :)

Comment: I got the JavaScript error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '$' "

Comment: `$('a.open_in_new_window').attr('target', '_blank');`  misplaced the code in hurry. Try this ;)

Comment: Not sure if I'm adding it in the wrong area. I have been testing in Chrome's debugger and entered the line you supplied in the console tab and it returns the <a class="open_in_new_window"> tag with the target parameter. I added your line like so: transition: 500
    };
    $('.rs-slideshow').rsfSlideshow(opts);
    
    $('a.open_in_new_window').attr('target', '_blank');
    
   });  
   
 </script>

Comment: I added my code using your example to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I have made the update in the code how now it works for you ;)

Comment: I added the line right after `$(document).ready(function () {` as you suggested, but still opens the link on the same page.

Comment: @Rick 
`$('a.open_in_new_window').attr('target', '_blank');

                });

            });     
`

replace this to 

`$('a.open_in_new_window').attr('target', '_blank');

                });

`

you have repeated accidentally `});` remove one

Comment: I updated my code above to reflect what I have been testing. Tested in Firefox and Opera and still get the same result :-(

Comment: OK, I got it!
Thanks to your code I just added a couple new lines in the Javascript:

`// Under if (slide.link_to)` ...
`if (slide.link_to_new_page) {
$img = $('<a href="' + slide.link_to_new_page + '" target="_blank"></a>').append($img);
}`

`// Under link_to: {selector: 'a', attr: 'data-link-to'},  ...
link_to_new_page: {selector: 'a', attr: 'data-link-to-new-page'}`,

And in the html changed` data-link-to=http://google.com` to `data-link-to-new-page=http://google.com`

Now if I just want to use the link and have it open in the same page I use data-link-to, otherwise data-link-to-new-page.

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
$('a').click(function() {
$(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

after

```
$('.rs-slideshow').rsfSlideshow(opts);
```

this will make all the links on the page open in a new window. If you had classes on the links, we can change the code to target those specific classes and open only the ones you want to select.

Comment: I had tried that but didn't work. Also, I forgot to mention that I don't want all links to open in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Because Really Simple Slideshow generates the HTML for each slide on the fly, just before the transition happens, you’ll need to target the links after they’re generated. You can do this by attaching to the `rsPostTransition` event:

```
$('#my-slideshow').bind('rsPostTransition', function() {
  $('#my-slideshow a.open_in_new_window').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Or you could use jQuery’s delegated events, which is probably the neater option:

```
$('#my-slideshow').on('click', 'a.open_in_new_window', function() {
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: No, that’s the ID of the element you’re applying the Really Simple Slideshow plugin to. For details about the jQuery syntax for delegated events, see the [docs for `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: So I would just use .rs-slideshow, per my example. Anyways I used `$('.rs-slideshow').bind('rsPostTransition', function() {
  $('.rs-slideshow a.open_in_new_window').attr('target', '_blank');
});` and `$('.rs-slideshow').on('click', 'a.open_in_new_window', function() {
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});`, but still opens in same window.